# OPC UA Model Compiler and Nodeset

Tags: xml, csv, opc-ua

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to generate the C code for the ua-Nodeset-1.04 (https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset) using the UA-ModelCompiler (https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/tree/v1.04).

I tried to follow the readme's but I'm not getting anywhere so I thought I would try to post about it, I seem to be able to run the BuildStandarTypes.bat but I'm not sure where the output stack ends up and I'm also not sure how to change it so that it grabs the files from the UA-Nodeset-1.04.

Does anyone have some suggestions or ideas how I can solve this?

Hope that its okay to post this here.

Steps so far :

1. Downloaded the files
2. Opened in Visual studio 2019
3. Built in Release mode (2 succeded, 0 failed)
4. Ran .\BuildStandarTypes.bat in PowerShell then I got

```
PS C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04> .\BuildStandardTypes.bat Building Model "StandardTypes"
Building Model GDS
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaGdsModel.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaGdsModel.csv" -o2 ".\Published\GDS\"
Copying Model files to .\Published\GDS\OpcUaGdsModel
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model DI
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.csv" -o2 ".\Published\DI\"
Copying Model files to .\Published\DI\OpcUaDiModel
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model ADI
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaAdiModel.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaAdiModel.csv" -o2 ".\Published\ADI\"
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.xml
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.csv
Copying Model files to .\Published\ADI\OpcUaAdiModel
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model PLCopen
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaPLCopenModel.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaPLCopenModel.csv" -o2 ".\Published\PLCopen\"
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.xml
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.csv
Copying Model files to .\Published\PLCopen\OpcUaPLCopenModel
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model MTConnect
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\MTConnectModel.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\MTConnectModel.csv" -o2 ".\Published\MTConnect\"
Copying Model files to .\Published\MTConnect\MTConnectModel
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model FDI
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaFDIPart5Model.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaFDIPart5Model.csv" -o2 ".\Published\FDI\"
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.xml
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.csv
Copying Model files to .\Published\FDI\OpcUaFDIPart5Model
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model FDI
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaFDIPart7Model.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaFDIPart7Model.csv" -o2 ".\Published\FDI\"
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.xml
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.csv
Copying Model files to .\Published\FDI\OpcUaFDIPart7Model
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Building Model Sercos
.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -d2 ".\ModelCompiler\Design\SercosModel.xml" -cg ".\ModelCompiler\Design\SercosModel.csv" -o2 ".\Published\Sercos\"
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.xml
Trying file: C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\ModelCompiler\Design\OpcUaDiModel.csv
Copying Model files to .\Published\Sercos\SercosModel
1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) copied.
Copying CSV files to .\Published\Schema\

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\ModelCompiler\Design\StandardTypes.csv" ".\Published\Schema\NodeIds.csv"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\ModelCompiler\Design\UA Attributes.csv" ".\Published\Schema\AttributeIds.csv"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\Published\DotNet\Opc.Ua.StatusCodes.csv" ".\Published\Schema\StatusCode.csv"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\Core\Schema\UANodeSet.xsd" ".\Published\Schema\UANodeSet.xsd"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\Core\Schema\SecuredApplication.xsd" ".\Published\Schema\SecuredApplication.xsd"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\Core\Types\Schemas\OPCBinarySchema.xsd" ".\Published\Schema\OPCBinarySchema.xsd"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\Core\Schema\ServerCapabilities.csv" ".\Published\Schema\ServerCapabilities.csv"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\ModelCompiler\Design\rec20_latest.csv" ".\Published\Schema\rec20_latest.csv"
1 file(s) copied.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>COPY ".\ModelCompiler\Design\UNECE_to_OPCUA.csv" ".\Published\Schema\UNECE_to_OPCUA.csv"
1 file(s) copied.
Updating License

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -input .\Published -pattern *.xml -license MITXML -silent
Updating 38 files.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -input .\Published -pattern *.xsd -license MITXML -silent
Updating 12 files.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -input .\Published -pattern *.bsd -license MITXML -silent
Updating 9 files.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -input .\Published -pattern *.cs -license MIT -silent
Updating 35 files.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -input .\Published -pattern *.h -license MIT -silent
Updating 8 files.

C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04>.\Bin\Release\Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -input .\Published -pattern *.c -license MIT -silent
Updating 3 files.
```

Anyone have so experience with generating OPC UA nodeset automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The `Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe` has an optional parameter to define the version `-version v104`, an example can be found in the [Data Types example](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples/blob/master/Workshop/DataTypes/Common/BuildDesign.bat) of OPC Foundation.

Comment: Not sure I follow, so I can use the Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe and then point to the xml and csv  and then it will output it in \Types?

Comment: yes, it will generate the output into the folder specified by -o2 parameter. Under [this](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/tree/v1.04/Schema) path you find all the  files to generate the V104 files (bsd, xsd, NodeSet2, ...)

Comment: I tried making a folder called Types in the C:\Model\UA-ModelCompiler-1.04\Bin\Release folder then copying the POWERLINK xml and csv files from the UA-Nodeset and running the command but I'm getting 

` Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe : The term 'Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe -version v104  -d2 ".\Types\Opc.Ua.POWERLINK ... `

Any ideas?